# for loop from A - Z with PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I can make the table perfectly if it's from A-Y but when it if I change it to 'Z', it won't work anymore.

Does anybody know the problem?

```
<table border="1">
<?php

    for($row=1; $row<=22; $row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($column="A"; $column <= "Y"; $column++){
            echo "<td> $row $column </td>";
        }   
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try with:

```
<table border="1">
<?php
   for ($row=1; $row <= 22; $row++){
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $column){
         echo "<td> $row $column </td>";
      }   
      echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be for instead of foreach?

Answer (score 5):

```
for($char = ord('a'); $row <= ord('z'); ++$char);
// chr($char) returns it to its character state
```

`ord()` returns the code of characters and makes them number like. `chr()` reverts them. Makes `for` easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `range()` but a `for` instead (as in your Original code), this should work:

```
<table border="1">
<?php

    for($row=1; $row<=22; $row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($column='A'; $column!='AA'; $column++){ 
            echo "<td> $row $column </td>";
        }   
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
for($column="A"; $column <= "Y"; $column++){
```

You are asking it to loop as long as it is < or = to Y, so it stops at Z. It should have been

```
for($column="A"; $column <= "Z"; $column++){
```

But as indicated range() would work nicely in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, `<= "Z"` doesn't work. A workaround is checking if `$column != "AA"`, because `AA` is the next value after `Z`

Comment: $column1="a";

        for($column=1; $column <= 26; $column++){
            echo "<td> $column1 </td>";
            $column1++;
        }